# Allow a user to write to sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am developing an application page in sharepoint 2010, in this page the users gets a list of available training courses, and there is a link to register to it.

The problem is that the common users does not have access to the list where the attendances are register, so if I run the application with an user with priviledges it works, but if I try to run it with a common user it fails.

What can i do?

Thanks for any advice ..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code block must run by the following code:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() {
    // write to list code ...
    }
```